# Svelte "Unused" CSS not compiling

Tags: css, svelte, tailwind-css

I'm creating a grid of text with slight border changes depending on the n-th child (which is determined according to screen size). However, svelte refers to these as unused css, even though they're defined. What could be the reason for such errors?

```
    {#each workWithUs as item, i}
                <div
                    class="border-r-[1px] border-b-[1px] border-work-with-us border-opacity-100 lg:cell-lg md:cell-md sm:cell-sm ">
                    <div class="p-5 m-5">
                        {#if i > 0}
                            <span class="dot mb-[2px]" />
                            <span class="ml-2">{item}</span>
                        {:else}
                            <span class="text-2xl font-medium">{item}</span>
                        {/if}
                    </div>
                </div>
    {/each}

<style>
    .dot {
        height: 7px;
        width: 7px;
        background-color: #67c529;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .cell-lg:nth-child(4n) { //unused css error here
        border-right-width: 0;
    }

    .cell-md:nth-child(3n) { //unused css error here
        border-right-width: 0;
    }

    .cell-sm:nth-child(2n) { //unused css error here
        border-right-width: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: The full class name is `lg:cell-lg`, not `cell-lg`. You should probably use a different class and media queries instead.

Comment: Is there a way to use tailwind media queries for custom classes?

Comment: You can either reproduce them in plain CSS (using the same measurements) or make a custom class with the breakpoints in the tailwind config. I've never used tailwind with Svelte, so I can't help you any more than that

Answer (score 0):

You aren't targeting the right classes in your CSS selectors. They need to be written as follows:

```css
.lg\:cell-lg:nth-child(4n) { 
    border-right-width: 0;
}

.md\:cell-md:nth-child(3n) { 
    border-right-width: 0;
}

.sm\:cell-sm:nth-child(2n) { 
    border-right-width: 0;
}
```